# xib-specified location moves on UIView load?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a couple of view controllers that I want all to share a header status bar. This header view shows status of certain things in my app. I used IB to lay out the contents of the header view in its own xib, then also used IB to layout the view controllers, adding a placeholder UIView element in the view controller's xibs for when I load in the header programmatically.

Now, when I create a UIView subclass from the contents of the view xib, and add that as a subview to the view of any of my view controllers, the location that I specified for the header view in my view controller xib seems to get ignored, and the header view gets placed at (0,0) no matter what. All the contents of the header view load and appear fine, it's just the location of the header view in the view controller that is wrong.

Here's how I'm loading and adding my header view to my view controller:

```
header = [InfoHeader loadFromNib:MY_NIB_NAME withOwner:self];
[self.view addSubview:header];
```

The view controller xib is confirmed to have an outlet connected to the 'header' variable. And here's that 'loadFromNib' method:

```
+(InfoHeader *) loadFromNib: (NSString *) nibName withOwner:(id) objectOwner
{
    NSBundle *b = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSArray *nib = [b loadNibNamed:nibName owner:objectOwner options:nil];

    InfoHeader *header;

    for (id obj in nib)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[InfoHeader class]])
        {
            header = (InfoHeader *) obj;
        }
    }

    return header;
}
```

Any ideas on what to check here? I'd rather not locate the header bar programmatically, but let IB do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the location of your subview in IB? Usually, the default location (0, 0) of the view will be the (top, left) coordinate of the big view in the screen. I think checking that will work fine

Comment: Yes, my subview is 44 pixels down from the top in IB. But, no matter where I place the UIView in IB, the displayed view shows up at (0,0).

Comment: Wait, your header view is just a view right, how can you put it 44 pixels down from the top in IB? I don't get your layout in IB to be honest

Comment: Yes, my header view is just a view within my view controller's main view. The view controller has the whole-screen view, and then I placed a smaller view (for my header) within that view. Wherever I place that UIView item in IB (top, bottom, wherever), it appears at the top when I run it.

Comment: I think you did it wrong. You already put the header in the IB, why do you need to addSubview any more. Did you connect your header view with the view the nib file?

Comment: Here is something wrong: when you call add subview:, your header will be loaded from the header nib and in there, it has different location. The ViewController's nib file contains the smaller view for nothing. If you want it to happens, you need to call `[self.yourPlacedHolderView addSubview:headerView];`

Comment: Thanks! You put me on the right track and I got it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using a "placeholder" view at all, by programmatically specifying the frame of the subview:

```
InfoHeader *header = [InfoHeader loadFromNib:MY_NIB_NAME withOwner:self];
header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, header.frame.size.width, header.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:header];
```

(that code asssumes that you have removed the `header` outlet from your class, so it can be a local variable instead).

Or, if you'd rather use the placeholder (so you can specify the header's position using IB instead of programmatically), do it like this:

```
InfoHeader *headerView = [InfoHeader loadFromNib:MY_NIB_NAME withOwner:self];
[header addSubview:headerView];
```